# What happens exactly when doing irregular calculations in C#?

Tags: c#, math

I'm currently implementing a function plotter, and I got everything working so far, except cases where I have to do irregular calculations such as `1/(x-2)`, `x=2`.

At the moment, my code looks like this (simplified, of course):

```
for(int i = minxvalue; i <= maxxvalue; i++) {
    double y = ParseFunction(functionstring); //Parses the given string containing the user-entered function and returns the resulting y-value as double
    coordinatelist.Add(new Coordinate(i, y);}//Saves the value-pair to a list with all valid points of the function-graph
```

My question is, what do I have to expect `y` to be in case of calculations as `Math.Sqrt(-2)`, `1/0` etc. So far I noticed that the affected calculation gets left out somehow since it doesn't appear in my coordinates-list, but there hast to be a return-value, right?

Comment: `but there hast to be a return-value, right?` - no. There will be an [exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception(v=vs.110).aspx) for divide by zero and a `NaN` for `Sqrt(-2)` which is also [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Indeed, there will be a `DivisionByZeroException` for operations like `1/0`. I would assume your `ParseFunction` contains a try-catch block somewhere and it swallows the exception.

Comment: As far as I can see from my code, there won't. When printing the results to the console in earlier states of the project, it printed `undefined` instead of the number but didn't throw any exception.

Comment: "undefined" is not a legal result of a number parsing in .NET. There has to be code in your project doing that conversion/formatting.

Comment: It might not have been `undefined` exactly, since VS2013 is set up in my native Language (German) and I just translated the output to English. Anyways, Noctis answer helped me out fairly well already, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation might return a `Not A Number` .

Probably need more code to see what happens, but here's the MSDN documentation on it: [**`NaN`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That might be it. Would explain the console-output when printing `y`. Will check this out, thanks.